# how to split json response as MultipartForm data with a given boundary value in Spring REST

Tags: multipartform-data, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

My Spring REST service responds with a huge json Response, 
i wanted to split that json with Multipart/form-data with some boundary value how could i do that,

this is what i tried

> headers.add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;
>   boundary='SOMEBOUNDRY_VALUE'");

But i don't know how to split the response object values, can i just put the phrase "SOMEBOUNDAY_VALUE" ? between the large attribute values of response object ?

any help would be a great help,  i'm using Spring Rest

Here is the Response i get from SOAP
[Response Header from SOAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev2NW.png)
[image]

response is not full and truncated though

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by manually adding delimiter after every json value of each attribute, if the attribute is more then 2mb in size then i split the attribute to 2MB and separated by adding delimiter to it,

the reason why we needed multipart/form-data in our service response is our security layer won't accept more then 2MB attribute value while processing it, so we split the large attribute in to arrayList and added delimiter at end of each array value, which can be re-phrased at client side which served the purpose

> headers.add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;
>   boundary='SOMEBOUNDRY_VALUE'");

still be there to indicate the response type is mulltipart/form-data along with the above specified delimiter logic